# How to implement my own rule in filter result in jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

This is my code:

```
   var projects = [{label:"PH2938", value: "1", fk: "3", desc: "hello"},
                   {label:"JUH28", value: "2", fk: "0", desc: "world"},];
                   {label:"HK383", value: "3", fk: "3", desc: "!"},];
     $( "#serial_no" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
                var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(projects, request.term);
                response(results);
            },
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
           $( "#serial_no" ).val( ui.item.label );
              return false;
           },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
           $( "#serial_no" ).val( ui.item.label );
           $( "#device_id" ).val( ui.item.value );
           $( "#device_model" ).text( ui.item.desc );
           return false;
        }
     })
     .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
     };
```

So now, for example, if I type 'H' in the field, all 3 results (i.e PH2938, JUH28, HK383) will be shown. My question is: is possible to make it only show the results (i.e. PH2938, HK383) whose fk = 3. That is, can I implement my own rule in showing which results.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly you need to filter the `projects` by some criteria. In this case by `fk` being equal to `'3'`.

As you are already using jQuery then [$.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) is the good candidate for the filtering task.

```
$.grep(projects, function (project) {
  return project.fk === '3';
});
```

Now we have to decide where to perform this filtering.

If you want to get rid of those projects that meet the `fk` criteria regardless of the term used in the autocompletion input, I would do it in the original `projects` array:

```
var projects = [{label:"PH2938", value: "1", fk: "3", desc: "hello"},
               {label:"JUH28", value: "2", fk: "0", desc: "world"},];
               {label:"HK383", value: "3", fk: "3", desc: "!"},];    
projects = $.grep(projects, function (project) {
  return project.fk === '3';
});
```

If what you want is something more flexible that allows you to provide a different data source depending on other criteria, not only the text matching of the label, then you can perform this filtering in the `source` property:

```
source: function(request, response) {
  var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(projects, request.term);
  // Filter the matched results by project fk 3. 
  results = $.grep(results, function (project) {
    return project.fk === '3';
  });
  response(results);
},
```

The filtering could be performed before the matching too:

```
source: function(request, response) {
  // Filter the matched projects by project fk 3. 
  var filteredProjects = $.grep(projects, function (project) {
    return project.fk === '3';
  });
  var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(filteredProjects, request.term);
  response(results);
},
```

See a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f9bbh0gg/2/) for the latter.